# What's causing this yahoo_fin get_quote_table error?

Tags: json, python-3.x, finance, yahoo-finance, computational-finance

I'm trying to get the live prices, previous close, and day's range with yahoo_fin's get_quote_table. It's been working with these errors occurring some of the time, but my program is able ... up until now. Today, I've constantly been getting these errors.

```
File "bot.py", line 120, in start
    price_opens[i] = get_quote_table(all_tickers[i])["Previous Close"]
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\yahoo_fin\stock_info.py", line 202, in get_quote_table
    quote_price = pd.DataFrame(["Quote Price", get_live_price(ticker)]).transpose()
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\yahoo_fin\stock_info.py", line 425, in get_live_price
    df = get_data(ticker, end_date = pd.Timestamp.today() + pd.DateOffset(10))
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\yahoo_fin\stock_info.py", line 78, in get_data
    raise AssertionError(resp.json())
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I've also been running this bot on Heroku, and the same issue occurs.
What could be causing this issue? Please help.

Edit: This error happens randomly. Sometimes, a certain ticker will fail, and another time, it'll work. However, today, it's been hectic and has been happening every time my bot starts up.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like one of two things has happened:  something is wrong with YF's service or (more likely) they're actively trying to limit the number of people hitting their endpoints programmatically.  The reason you're getting a `JSONDecodeError` is that there's a 404 error:

[image]

You can hack your way around it though with a while loop and try / except block:

```
while True:
    try:
        # your code here
        break
    except ValueError: # ValueError will catch the JSONDecodeError
        continue
```